# How can I reserve a name for an application on Blackberry App world?

Tags: blackberry

My small startup is planning to start development of a blackberry app in september. My CEO wants to register the name for the app beforehand. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Why the negative votes, folks?  This is a legit question..

Comment: It's not on-topic for stackoverflow, since it's a business question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You can go into the App World admin pages and create a new application, and just not upload binaries.  I'm not sure if that actually reserves the name or not, but it's probably about as much as you can do.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no point in reserving a name with the BlackBerry App store.  Other vendors can just put up an app with the exact same names.  Turst me:  the Blackberry Developer world is upset by this, but RIM just looks the other way.  Their store is an absolute MESS.

http://www.blackberrycool.com/2011/02/21/should-application-storefronts-allow-app-name-duplication/

http://www.blackberrygames.info/2011/02/rim-allows-duplicate-app-names/